# How to define bootstrap tokenfield to work with textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to define [tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#examples) on a textarea with more height but its displaying as a textbox (single line). How can I customize the tokenfield to work with a textarea?

```
<textarea name="f1_email" placeholder="Enter Friends's Email separated by comma" class="f1-facebook form-control" rows="10" cols="30" id="f1-referral-email"></textarea>
```

```js
$('#f1-referral-email').on('tokenfield:createdtoken', function (e) {
    var valid = isEmail(e.attrs.value);
    if (!valid) {
        $(e.relatedTarget).addClass('invalid')
    }
}).tokenfield()
```

---

ACTUAL OUTPUT:
[image]

Any help or advice is appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Give it rows attribute like this - `<textarea rows="8">`

Comment: I tried that but worthless. You can see the code above

Comment: remove the `rows` and `cols`?

Comment: I tried that too but not working.

Answer (score 0):

As what stated [here](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/issues/117), tokenfield can be adjusted by it's CSS`(bootstrap-tokenfield.css)`. Please examine and look for `(input-sm, input-lg etc)`. This is just a hack to create a `custom textarea`. Then select the appropriate class in your `input` tag. Or if you wanted to create a custom size refer to code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-xl">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-tokenfield">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-group.form-group-xl .form-control {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.form-group.form-group-xl .tokenfield {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I tried to edit the input, but instead of being multi-line just the height of input is increased. This caused text to display middle of long input. :)